# jquery document ready in external script

Tags: jquery, scripting, external, onload

My page has an outside script that contains some jQuery. Most of it runs fine except this bit:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('x');                        
});
```

That bit of code works fine when i run it inside the HTML page but not in the .js file.
I have no other library in the HTML, i do have a window.onload inside the HTML but if i remove it, the jQuery bit still does not work. And it does not generate any error message.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 26):

As this was the problem in [this discussion](http://www.nabble.com/using-doc.ready-in-an-external-.js-file-td18349722s27240.html), are you sure that you include jQuery **before** including your external script ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="externalScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: I think this was the link: http://jquery.10927.n7.nabble.com/using-doc-ready-in-an-external-js-file-td74946.html although it provide little more information than that given in the answer